# Copying a class object

Tags: ruby

I have an instance object named layers
which is an array of Layer objects.

I try the following, and I get an error saying that I'm trying to dump a class method:

```
@best_copy = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(@layers))

TypeError: no marshal_dump is defined for class Method
```

How do I make it so that it isn't trying to save the attr_accessor,
but the actual object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like one or more of your Layers has an instance variable that's a Method. Does that sound right? Marshal sends an object `marshal_dump` to get the data for marshaling, and in turn the object's attributes also get `marshal_dump` to get their data. Methods cannot be marshaled, so when the process gets to that part of object, it gets hung up trying to marshal your method.

Comment: Ah yeah.. I just realized.. I have a function pointer.   attr_accessor :fptr. Is there an alternative to this? besides removing the function pointer, or saving individual parts of the object.

Comment: @user487980: There is no alternative in the general case — you can't marshal methods. Objects with executable code in an instance variable just don't interact well with the standard archiving libraries. The closest approximation would be a Cocoa-like system of storing a target (the object that implements the Method) and a selector (the message to invoke the Method). So, for example, if you're doing `@fptr = foo.method(:bar)`, you would instead do `@target = foo; @selector = :bar`.